# How to properly setup intel and nvidia GPUs on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, drivers, graphics-card, gpu

So, it seems bumblebee is dead and abandoned. The last serious activity on the repo is from 2013. Apparently, the current "good" solution is the one [described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867482/nvidia-drivers-not-working-bumblebee-and-nvidia-x-server-settings): every time I want to use Nvidia GPU, I have to at least logout and log back in (apparently the Nvidia tool to choose between Intel and Nvidia changes the initramfs, so I thought I had to reboot) and now my laptop uses twice the power (I can feel the much increased heat from the vent), I have to reconfigure my monitor setup, and I can no longer use the Intel GPU (I can see it listed in Vulkan devices, but trying to use it gives me an error). Is that the "state of art" of Nvidia on Linux laptop?

Can't I have both GPUs available, Intel working most of the time, and decide to use Nvidia on a per application basis (or maybe both simultaneously, as I have done with AMD+Intel via Vulkan)? My device is a ThinkPad T480.

Comment: No, you can't have both regardless of the OS. The only difference is the Nvidia drivers in Windows allow toggling the dGPU seamlessly. this "on demand" feature can be enabled in Linux for newer cards and drivers but it's stil experimental.

Comment: @ChanganAuto After asking this question, I found this documentation: https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/435.17/README/primerenderoffload.html
The section "Finer-Grained Control of Vulkan" seems to imply that what I want is indeed possible, but I haven't managed to make it work yet to write a full answer.

Comment: No, it doesn't. And nothing on that document is required to set manually. Installing the recommended driver from the Ubuntu official repositories (as you should always do) also installs `nvidia-prime`, the package that manages the GPU switch. That all. Then open Nvidia X Server settings and look for the "on demand" profile. If available you may try it; if not then you'll have to select the intended GPU, logout and login, or reboot.

Comment: You could try to disable the integrated Intel graphics in the BIOS completely. So you have the faster NVidia for everything. Then see how the power consumption is... I think it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, I found the official NVIDIA documentation on how to do what is called "[PRIME Render Offload](https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/525.53/README/primerenderoffload.html)". Basically it creates a X screen attached to your low power GPU (Intel in my case, but it seems to work with integrated AMD, too), and on specific applications, you "offload" the work to the dedicated GPU, which must also be loaded by the X server.

#### Vulkan

It works transparently with Vulkan, with both devices being listed and available to the applications. Contrary to the docs linked above, setting environment variable `__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1` made no difference for vulkan, and NVIDIA device was always available. This is a screenshot of one vkcube running on Nvidia and other on Intel:
[image: two vkcubes on different GPUs]

#### OpenGL

To use Nvidia GPU with OpenGL applications, you have to set environment variables `__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia`, otherwise the integrated GPU will be used by default. Following is a screenshot of two `glxgear` running simultaneously in different GPUs:
[image: two glxgears on different GPUs]

#### How to Setup in Ubuntu

I just followed the instructions on [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaDriversInstallation), which boiled down to running the command:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install nvidia:525
```

I also tried to setup automatic fine-grained power management by following the instructions in the manual page "[PCI-Express Runtime D3 (RTD3) Power Management](https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/525.53/README/dynamicpowermanagement.html)", but my GPU is too old and doesn't have support for it. I don't know if it had any effect on my system, but when I run `nvidia-settings`, the PRIME profile "Intel (Power Saving Mode)" is greyed out and not available. I don't know why, it was working a day before, it might have something to do with messing with kernel drivers arguments in the failed setup.

For the PRIME render offload to work (and not simply run everything on the discrete GPU) I selected PRIME profile NVIDIA On-Demand:
[image: prime profiles]

Then, if you have a recent enough driver version, a recent enough Xorg, your BIOS happens to boot on the integrated GPU and the stars align, X will automatically load both GPUs and create the screen using the integrated one without having to mess with `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. You can see if it happened by running `xrandr --listproviders`. It should have two lines more or less like this:

```
$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x46 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 3 outputs: 5 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
Provider 1: id: 0x20e cap: 0x0 crtcs: 0 outputs: 0 associated providers: 0 name:NVIDIA-G0
```

And that is it. I have no idea if I did something else that enabled the render offloading or if it was already working from start on the first time I decided to install NVIDIA drivers, and I didn't knew because somehow I missed the NVIDIA GPU listed among the Vulkan devices (or maybe the ICD json file was created the first time I changed the PRIME profile to "NVIDIA (Performance Mode)", who knows?), coupled with bad information I got googling for the "NVIDIA On-Demand" profile, which said that it was an off-screen CUDA thing and said nothing about the environment variables for selecting the GPU on OpenGL applications.

Comment: So how it works under Wayland? Lenovo T560 (GeForce 940MX) user here.